# Usage of cytoscape.js for pipleline development

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to understand if I can use cytoscape.js for my protptype work. Here is what I want:

1. Create a pipeline via rectangle node connecting to another node(s) horizontally.
2. Changing node property say it color or border on tab or click. Also creating on tap want to create menu or combobox to select something or to perform some action.
3. Drag and drop some outside file into the node canvas, which should either create new connected node or consumed by first node for some action...etc

Now my question/confusion is that if cytoscape.js is suitable for above purpose.

I am able to create pipeline (1 step above) but not sure if I can do 2 and 3rd step via Cytoscape.js

Did some one accomplish similar stuff as I described above. If yes can you please share some examples.

Or 
Please let me know if Cytoscape.js is not meant for above describe purpose and what other lib I can use

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape.js is a graph theory / network library.  It does not cover general UI widgets etc, as that is very much out of scope.  You can use Cytoscape.js for everything you want, using other libraries or your own code where appropriate.

Comment: Hi Max,  Thanks for the response. Now little confused about " You can use Cytoscape.js for everything you want" as us said in first line that it is a graph theory...  Also using what other libraries. can u give some example. thank you

Comment: In terms of external libraries, you'll have to explore other libraries and read their docs to find what meets your requirements.  An example of integration with other libraries is the qtip extension (https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip), though it's not necessary to make an extension to use libraries together.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to create something like http://gojs.net/latest/samples/pipes.html ?

GoJS can do everything that you ask for. Disclaimer: I helped create http://gojs.net.